# Why do my line numbers keep disappearing in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I want to display line numbers in my Android Studio editors.

I have turned line numbers ON in preferences

`Preferences > Editor > Appearance`

However, line numbers do not appear.

If I drop down the View menu and look at the `Show Line Numbers` option, it is NOT checked.

`View > Active Editor > Show Line Numbers`

If I check it, line numbers show.  However, if I move my cursor to a different character or line, they immediately disappear.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

as @pgoggijr said already, this is a problem I was having with IDEAVim as well. however, you don't have to turn vim off. Just use the vim commands

```
:set nu
```

and

```
:set nonu
```

to toggle line numbers on and off, and these stay :)

---

Disclaimer: I wrote that doc

Comment: If it weren't for this question+answer, I'd never know it was the IdeaVim plugin. I couldn't find documentation for this.

Comment: As an FYI to IdeaVim users, the plugin will read your `~/.vimrc`. I placed `set nu` in there as I was getting inconsistent behavior, and having to manually reset this upon opening the IDE.

Comment: Rider was driving me insane! This worked in Rider `2018.2.x` perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you're using the ideaVim emulator.

There seems to be a bug in the ideaVim plugin that has surfaced in recent versions of Android Studio that makes line numbers disappear once the cursor moves

Turn off the emulator (tools > VIM emulator), and it should be fine.